# Single MySQL lookup for each distinct set of rows

Tags: mysql, join, foreach

I have a table of 5Million rows, but only about 9000 distinct values in column A, and need to populate another column (B) using a lookup from another table.
I need to run something like:

```
UPDATE t SET t.B=(SELECT lookupValue FROM lookuptable WHERE b.lookupKey = X) WHERE t.A=X
```

where X takes on each of the distinct 9000 values.

Is there a single query that can do this, or do I have to resort to doing in in the application or a stored-proc?

I tried doing the lot at once:

```
UPDATE t SET B=(SELECT lookupValue FROM lookuptable WHERE b.lookupKey = t.A)
```

But that does a lookup for each one of the 5Million rows and takes too long (If a lookup takes one second, that's ~5Million seconds, rather than 9000 seconds).

Comment: While the latter case is arguably better written as a JOIN (I avoid sub-selects in most every case), the query planner could technically turn it into an equivalent plan as that used in a JOIN (i.e. it doesn't need to look up each item in a separate query) - to tell what *actually* occurs requires looking at the query plan used. Also, keep indices in mind. (Maybe I'm just spoiled because I use SQL Server? I include plan generation with most every query ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with an `INNER JOIN` query, it should be faster

```
UPDATE t 
INNER JOIN lookuptable b
ON b.lookupKey = t.A
SET t.B= b.lookupValue
```

Comment: You said INNER JOIN, but then wrote LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @user2246674 MySQL's optimization is not very good, it generally does JOINs best

Comment: I tested this query on a single value (adding WHERE t.A = 123 for the test). If working, I would have expected it to complete in around a second. I stopped it after 60 seconds had passed.

I think either MySQL isn't clever enough to optimise this to just do a single lookup, or my addition of "WHERE t.A = 123" didn't work the way I expected.

Comment: For the record, I ended up speeding up the lookup query using a temporary MEMORY table copy of the lookup table and then using a join. Not scalable, and I think it might have done 5 Million joins, but it was fast enough that it worked for my one-shot purposes.

Comment: @Crash i'm glad i was helpfull and you found out a way to solve  the issue!